# Array not declared in this scope when call Function

Tags: c++, arrays

Im having some isues when I try to run my C++ program.
What does it do is ask the user for the size of the array and what type of array is, double or int, then depending on the user choise, it declares the array, then it calls a function that fills the array with user values

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
void fill(T *arr,int size){
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i ++){
                cout<<"Insert value " << i << " :" ;
                cin >> arr[i];
        }
}
int main(){
        int option,size;
        cout << "Size? ";
        cin >> size;
        cout << "1 = double" << endl
        << "2 = int" << endl;
        cin >> option;
        if(option == 1){
                double arr[size];
        }
        else if(option == 2){
                int arr[size];
        }
        fill(arr,size);
return 0;
}
```

But when I try to run it, I got this error

> test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: test.cpp:24:7: error: ‘arr’ was
>   not declared in this scope   fill(arr,size);
>          ^

Comment: I think you need to take a step back, and start over with [a couple of good beginners books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Or at the very least research *scoping*. A good book should also teach you that C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), so your code is invalid in more than one way.

Comment: @Victor Oyervides  The arrays in this code snippet         if(option == 1){
                double arr[size];
        }
        else if(option == 2){
                int arr[size];
        } are declared in the scopes of the if and else statements and are not visible outside these statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `main()`, your `arr` variables are only in scope of the `if()` blocks that declare them.  They go out of scope when the `if`'s closing `}` is reached.  So they are indeed not in scope where `fill()` is being called.

Not that it would matter anyway, because you can't declare a variable with multiple types anyway.  So, you would not be able to declare a single `arr` array variable in `fill()`'s scope and have the array type be `int` or `double` based on user input (well, unless you use [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) or [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any), but that is a topic of its own).

You will need to call `fill()` inside of the `if()` blocks, where the arrays are in scope.

Also, you are relying on a *non-standard* vendor-specific extension known as "Variable Length Arrays", aka allocating a variable sized array in automatic (stack) memory instead of dynamic (heap) memory.  Only some compilers implement that extension as an extra feature.  Don't rely on it.  The correct way to allocate an array of variable size is to use `new[]` instead, or better [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Try something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
void fill(T *arr, int size){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i ++){
        std::cout << "Insert value " << i << " :";
        std::cin >> arr[i];
    }
}

int main(){
    int option, size;

    std::cout << "Size? ";
    std::cin >> size;
    std::cout << "1 = double" << std::endl
              << "2 = int" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> option;

    if (option == 1) {
        std::vector<double> arr(size);
        fill(&arr[0], size);
    }
    else if (option == 2) {
        std::vector<int> arr(size);
        fill(&arr[0], size);
    }

    return 0;
}
```